# Como hago un boton para ir para arriba con javascript nativo

Tags: javascript, scroll

¿Como puedo implementar la funcionalidad `scroll-to-top` sin jquery?

Como se muestra en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$('html, body').animate( { scrollTop : 0 }, 800 );
```

Quiero lograr algo como se muestra en esta pagina pero sin jquery
https://cybmeta.com/scroll-arriba-jquery

Comment: La pregunta es muy vaga. Agrega una breve descripción de lo que has buscado/investigado y ten presente que las preguntas que incluyen lo que se ha intentado usualmente son muy bien recibidas. ref. [ask].

Comment: Ya probaste con `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` ?

Comment: No he probado, creo una funcion en la que al darle al boton se realize el window.scrollTo(0, 0)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes asignarle el uso del método `scrollTo()`

**Botón HTML**

```
<button>Regresar al inicio</button>
```

**Código JS**

```
  <script>
    let btn = document.querySelector("button")

    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    })
  </script>
```

Este método recibe 2 valores, los cuales equivalen a las coordenadas en pixeles dentro del documento donde se posicionará.

Gracias a la recomendación de @anayarojo, revisé y para lograr el efecto de desplazamiento **(aunque con CSS)** se puede usar la propiedad: `scroll-behavior` con una propiedad llamada `smooth`

Quedando el código final así:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <style>
        html {
          scroll-behavior: smooth;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores quod eius, nemo recusandae soluta veniam quas dolorem, error, molestiae explicabo culpa voluptatem ipsa quos tempora unde? Saepe magnam aut corporis!</div>
      <div>Soluta obcaecati cumque aliquam suscipit officia hic laborum necessitatibus, assumenda, distinctio perferendis nesciunt quod quidem quo accusamus ex et esse? Ducimus aut autem consequuntur iusto quibusdam repellat, quia excepturi dolores!</div>
      <div>Soluta magni dignissimos amet porro, recusandae fugit ratione consequatur laboriosam nemo rerum accusantium, alias culpa, modi id laborum explicabo iusto laudantium. Iusto facere laudantium ipsa voluptatem aspernatur illum minima qui.</div>
      <div>Fugit, esse. Quas fuga porro non beatae quisquam ad quos fugiat, ratione harum qui atque officia inventore eum vel enim! Repellat hic assumenda corporis. Dicta doloremque voluptates, animi provident cumque.</div>
      <div>Culpa nostrum officiis maiores. Illo quam repellat distinctio incidunt officiis magni impedit vero, consectetur sit, quos dolorum. Quis nobis, suscipit ex recusandae beatae molestias, architecto odit voluptates nesciunt, adipisci, iste.</div>
      <div>Fugit, quae. Accusamus corrupti, magnam et impedit odio, hic dolorum fugiat, voluptas ullam recusandae blanditiis saepe asperiores quisquam iste officia esse nostrum voluptate iusto optio tempore eveniet. Ullam, vero, accusamus.</div>
      <div>Vitae nemo exercitationem magnam iure modi sequi distinctio reprehenderit porro quisquam illo libero cum non explicabo, maiores perspiciatis aliquam, nam reiciendis rem labore expedita tenetur. Esse consequuntur ipsa voluptates corporis.</div>
      <div>Expedita voluptatibus nisi, ad doloremque aliquid quas aperiam minima eius iste debitis vero cumque vel, natus ex explicabo nesciunt adipisci asperiores rerum dolore aut tempore! Accusantium voluptates illum mollitia nostrum.</div>
      <div>Deleniti qui dolor quam accusantium quidem vero numquam aliquam officiis aliquid, recusandae dolorem sunt iste unde ipsam temporibus corporis, adipisci vel nulla, et incidunt ea optio deserunt. Nostrum, blanditiis cum?</div>
      <div>Vel assumenda est earum laborum commodi vero saepe qui officia tempora explicabo dolorum quaerat magnam officiis quisquam sint, rerum in excepturi tempore, illo consequatur ipsum similique. Suscipit mollitia expedita odio.</div>
      <div>Reprehenderit, soluta, hic. Quod ad iusto qui nam esse, nobis optio labore dolorem repellat dignissimos. Ducimus ullam, voluptatem, rem at modi itaque pariatur impedit omnis magni, assumenda cupiditate inventore nulla.</div>
      <div>Nihil et ipsum mollitia amet culpa odit delectus animi ab eligendi eum eos deserunt provident eaque, ducimus cum. Voluptatibus, aut architecto aperiam voluptatem minus excepturi! Accusamus accusantium, ea magnam eius!</div>
      <div>Error beatae incidunt velit! Doloribus alias velit, porro quibusdam, nulla veniam. Consequatur sit possimus placeat quia quas alias, deserunt a ad explicabo sed, suscipit aliquam debitis delectus cupiditate est eius.</div>
      <div>Sint distinctio labore perspiciatis quibusdam, sapiente minima eveniet rerum! Soluta blanditiis asperiores magnam debitis a quisquam vel voluptas illo praesentium nemo, quo dolore sunt harum quasi pariatur alias reiciendis! Obcaecati.</div>
      <div>Doloremque fuga, optio enim. Aperiam soluta modi laborum odit, voluptates aut a voluptatum hic ipsa, harum consequuntur doloribus quia? Hic in asperiores mollitia cumque illo qui dignissimos ratione quisquam necessitatibus.</div>
      <div>Accusantium ipsum nihil nostrum nisi, ducimus provident commodi, tempore error labore mollitia quasi modi excepturi nulla maxime impedit aliquid laudantium vero natus. Explicabo omnis quas architecto quia voluptatibus at eius.</div>
      <div>Ipsam ipsum corporis eius repellendus impedit quidem molestias quasi quisquam labore, rem aliquam similique officiis, itaque amet perspiciatis recusandae ducimus commodi sed veritatis dolorem, magnam eum et maiores dolor? Natus?</div>
      <div>Alias quia eos deserunt quo quas praesentium dicta magnam veniam facere, facilis perferendis, maiores inventore id modi? Voluptas, atque, ipsam. Sapiente, quod. Nulla doloribus iusto illum rerum est nostrum doloremque.</div>
      <div>Cupiditate quasi tenetur incidunt soluta veniam iusto officia eos quae voluptatem officiis nam, numquam totam sunt aliquid placeat maiores, delectus perspiciatis blanditiis. Distinctio ducimus alias porro, facere accusantium error eveniet!</div>
      <div>Incidunt corporis doloremque nulla perferendis, nostrum porro quae quod quis provident, ratione a omnis eum nesciunt accusantium sunt repellendus debitis, quas, nobis maiores fugit ipsa dolores. Tempora dignissimos qui, aperiam.</div>
      <button>Ir arriba</button>
    <script>
       let btn = document.querySelector("button")
    
        btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
          window.scrollTo(0, 0)
        })
    </script>
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

> Sin embargo es importante aclarar que aún esta en borrador, se puede verificar en este enlace el soporte que tiene en los navegadores:

- [Soporte en navegadores](https://caniuse.com/#search=scroll-behavior)
- [Borrador de la especificación](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#propdef-scroll-behavior)

*Preferí consultar enlaces con mejor reputación que el recomendado, pero igual gracias a quien me hizo la observación.*

Comment: si me funciono ecepto lo del efecto suave, lo unico que hace esa funcion es esperar 1 segundo para que se ejecute

Comment: Para el efecto suave `smooth` utiliza el siguiente estilo `html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }` para esa animación. Aquí la [documentación](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp)

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación @anayarojo lo revisé y anexé a la respuesta

Comment: Buen trabajo @Aprendiz